# How to get Windows Service and ASP.NET MVC project interacting?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've two separated projects being one of them a Windows Service having another one has a reference.

I want my Service to call a method from the referenced project, something like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
    MessageSystem msg_system = new MessageSystem();

    IQueryable<MensagemGrupo> mensagens = 
        msg_system.GetScheduledMensagensGrupo();

    foreach (var msg in mensagens) {
        msg_system.ConfirmaEnvio(DateTime.Now, msg.id);
    }
```

The code i'm invoking throw the Service:

```
public class MessageSystem {
    private StorageModelDataContext db = new StorageModelDataContext();

    public IQueryable<MensagemGrupo> GetScheduledMensagensGrupo() {
        IQueryable<MensagemGrupo> mensagens = db.GetMensagensGrupoAgendadas();

        return mensagens;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a System.NullReferenceException starting at db.GetMensagensGrupoAgendadas(). Could it be because db is in a remote server?

Can i call methods this way from the service?

PS: The Service is LocalSystem. I've tried Network Service but i get "Error 5: Access Denied" while starting the service.

Comment: You want the Service to call the ASP.NET MVC code?

Comment: Yes. The class MessageSystem is a model.

Comment: Did you add the model connectionstring into the app.config of your service (like the one you find in web.config)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem using a Web Service in the ASP.NET MVC app that is executed thought the windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to call this via a web server, or do you just want to run the same code that's in your ASP.NET MVC app within your Service?

If it's the latter and you're calling a remote server that uses integrated authentication, your service has to run as a user that is valid on the remote server (that user will need 'logon as a service' rights to be able to run the service).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call this via a web server, or do you just want to run the same code that's in your ASP.NET MVC app within your Service?

If it's the latter and you're calling a remote server that uses integrated authentication, your service has to run as a user that is valid on the remote server (that user will need 'logon as a service' rights to be able to run the service).

If you want to use it as a webservice (ie. the ASP.NET MVC code runs on a server and you make requests to it from your service), you should add a web reference to the appropriate URL your ASP.NET MVC application exposes, not a normal project reference to the project.  See [Scott's post on mixing ASP.NET WebForms with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) and look at the example with the ASMX service for more details on creating the web service, then add a web reference (or service reference) to that ASMX from your service project.

[edited to clarify the web service option after seeing jvalente's comment]

Comment: Service and MVC app are in the same machine. Now i realized that i can't even get a string from the model. I'm doing something wrong. Is there any particularity to get a service "talking" with the model?